logistic regression coefficient interpretation - with / without interaction
In this model:
d = data.frame(f1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), 
               f2 = c('C', 'D', 'C', 'D'), 
               n = c(30, 22, 40, 36),      # Number of events
               r = c(100, 100, 100, 100))  # Group size

m = glm(cbind(n, r - n) ~ f1 + f2, data = d, family = binomial)
coef(m)

(Intercept)         f1B         f2D 
 -0.9101981   0.5587887  -0.2810226 

What does the intercept represent?
I thought it was the log odds of the event occurring in the f1 = A, f2 = C group, but I'm having trouble recreating that number by hand.
There's 30 events out of 100 people in the f1 = A, f2 = C group, but this doesn't give the log odds in the R output:
$$
\ln\left(\frac{30}{70}\right) = -0.847 \neq -0.910
$$
I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious here. If I fit a saturated model, then the intercept is the log odds in the f1 = A, f2 = C group:
m2 = glm(cbind(n, r - n) ~ f1 * f2, data = d, family = binomial)
coef(m2)

(Intercept)         f1B         f2D     f1B:f2D 
 -0.8472979   0.4418328  -0.4183685   0.2484695 

